# How do I parse html elements from an observable array of objects in rxjs

Tags: javascript, html, angular, rxjs, rss

In angular 8 I am parsing a wordpress rss feed and using one of its properties, 'content' to build a news scroller.  The rss feed is processed into a javascript object using rss-parser from node.js.

I need to parse out a http link, an image and a few chars of text from between paragraph (p) elements'. My problem is that the data I need is contained within the 'content' property and I don't know the encoding or how to parse out the link, image and text and place them into variables I can use within the observable.

Using Angular and rxjs I am able to derive an array of objects that includes each article and the property I need. 
`const http$ = this.api.rssSource$();` which is from the angular api.service.ts that gets the feed and returns an observable.  Then I map it down to the array of objects using this code:

`this.newsItems$ = http$
      .pipe(
        map(res => Object.values(res['items'])));` and I get this array of 20 items

`(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

each object within the array above looks like this:

`{content: "<a href="https://example.com/"><img width="300" height="200" src="https://example.com/some-image-300x200.jpeg" alt="blah blah blah"  /></a><p>A lot of text about something and then something else</p><br /><p>jabber jabber and more jabber</p>↵<p><a href="https://example.com/example.html/" rel="nofollow">...Read More About Blah And Jabber</a></p>↵}`

using `<div [innerHTML]="item.content"></div>` in the angular template I can render html with an image and a lot of text.  However, it is not in the format I want and needs to be shortened and re-arranged. I only need the complete 'a href="https://xxx..." ', 'img src="http://xxx..." ' and a single 'p xxxx /p'.

How can I access the object so that I can then further parse it to populate variables for newsLink, newsImg, shortDes?

Comment: I think that if you add it to the DOM inside a hidden div with a template variable, then you can use it in the component code with `@ViewChild(templateVariable)` and see the tree of elements once it is rendered, in `ngAfterViewInit()`.  From there you can pull what you want and use it elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your input @dmcgrandle! I actually tried this approach early on but my code was getting pretty weedy so I tried to factor it down.  I'm pretty sure your approach will work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you wish to do is manipulate each Object in the emitted array, you can add an array `map` call inside the RxJS `map` call:

```js
this.newsItems$ = http$.pipe(
  map(res => Object.values(res['items']).map(item => {
    // do item modification here
  }))
);
```

This will return the modified array. Alternatively, you can split the array and have it emitted as individual values, and then RxJS `map` them to modify them:

```js
this.newsItems$ = http$.pipe(
  switchMap(items => from(items)),
  map(item => // manipulate individual items here)
);
```

As for the actual parsing itself, that can be achieved using regular expressions and the `match()` function:

```js
arrayOfAnchorTags = item.content.match(/<\s*a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\s*\s*a>/g);
```

Comment: Thank you @Will Alexander for the response. I understand what you are saying from the rxjs standpoint. Where I'm having trouble is the actual parsing of the object. I don't know how to "pluck" out the info/html elements from within the 'content' property.  My instinct is to use a getter like "getElementByTagName('p')", however, data/body of the 'content' property doesn't appear to be accessible html, rather its a js object that at this point I'm having trouble accessing.  Any help you or anyone could is appreciated.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add one example of using regex and `match` to extract the anchor tags. You simply need to apply the same kind of logic for the various other elements.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you => this is exactly what I needed. I had to adjust some of my type definitions making `newsItems$: Observable<any>;` then I was able to map items.content down to a string.  From there .match() was the solution I was missing.  I'll go back and try to tighten up my type definitions.  Thank you @Will-Alexander for your help.

Comment: No worries :) don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in case anyone else has the same issue!

Comment: In case you're interested here is the final code: `this.newsItems$ = this.http$.pipe(
      map(res => Object.values(res['items'])
        .map(item => {const v = item['content'].toString()
          .match(/<\s*[ap][^>]*>(.*?)<\/\s*\s*[ap]>/g); return v; }
        )));'  For whatever reason it wouldn't work without the `return v;` I just piped it up to the template with the elements using `[innerHTML]="v[i]" ` and it worked perfectly.  Thank you again!